# How can i calculate a table and create a query with 4 different calculation in single column

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is : Management is proposing to increase the price of movies based on their rating using the following percentage scale:

```
‘14A’, 25%; 
‘18A’, 15%; 
‘A’, 10%; 
all others 5%.
```

Create a list that displays the movie name, rating type, current rental amount and revised rental amount. Column headings should be ‘Movie Name’, ‘Rating’, ‘Current Rental Price’, ‘New Rental Price’. The current and new rental prices must be formatted as currency with 2 decimal positions. Sort the list by rating. If there is more than a single movie in a category then sort by the movie name as a secondary sort.

```
SELECT Name AS "Movie Name", Rating, RentalAmount AS "Rental Amount",  
           TO_CHAR(RentalAmount * 1.25, '999.99') AS "Revised Amount"  
FROM Movies  
ORDER BY Rating , Name;
```

Comment: Please post the SQL you have tried

Comment: That's not a question- that's a requirement.  Which part specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Do you have any data you are working with? Can you mock some to show us?

Comment: Hie i dont need any solution , I just need hint on how can i achieve four calculation in a single row.

Comment: Which part of the question can you solve? Show at least you are doing an effort here.

Comment: Hie i have just added my query just confused where to add other three calculation

Comment: Hint : You can use CASE WHEN THEN ELSE here for your conditions on column 'rating'.
Refer this for help http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Comment: You don't need to use TO_CHAR to display numbers; if you don't want too many decimals in the result, you can use `round(.... , 2)`. If you leave the results as numbers (as I suggest), they will be aligned to the right, as they should be. Now to your question: instead of `RentalAmount * 1.25 as...`, you should have `RentalAmount * (case rating when '14A' then 1.25 when ... then ...  else 1.05 end) as ...`.  Read about `CASE` from the link posted by @Pat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query increase the value of 'RentalAmount' based on 'Rating':

```
SELECT Name AS "Movie Name", Rating, RentalAmount AS "Current Rental Price",  
  TO_CHAR(RentalAmount*decode(Rating, '14A', 1.25, '18A', 1.15, 'A', 1.1, 1.05), '999.99') AS "New Rental Price"  
FROM Movies  
ORDER BY Rating, Name
```